# ArrayoutofBounds exception found cannot be resolved

Tags: java, arrays

```
class Solution {
    public int[] solution(int[] A, int K) {
      for (int a = 0; a <= K; a++) {
          for (int j = 0; j < A.length - 1; j++) {
              A[j + 1] = A[j];
              A[0] = A[A.length];
          }
      }
      return A;
    }
}
```

What is wrong with this code? The next integer should be assigned the value of the previous one and the first one the value of the last one.

Comment: `A[0]=A[A.length];`, index start from 0, so subtract its length by 1, `A[A.length-1]`

Answer (score 0):

It's `A[A.length]` that causes the error. You forgot to remove 1:

```
A[0]=A[A.length-1];
```

And `a<=K` as well, so change it to `a<K`.

Comment: I did that but I get the wrong output as well. Can you help me out with that?